# Trying to change the color of bash prompt depending on CWD. Can't get it to update after changing directories

Tags: bash, prompt, truncate, ps1

I have two storage drives and am trying to configure my bashrc file to do this:

If the cwd is on drive B :

- Truncate the bash prompt to begin at the /home directory of the second drive
- Change the color of bash prompt to red to know I am working in the other drive.

So far I have been able to accomplish changing the color with the following code and can truncate the entire prompt to only show the basename by using the '\W' modifier -- but am struggling with how to trim the PROMPT_COMMAND by specifying a bottom directory...

**i.e.**

/media/devj/2a24a03f-99a1-44bd-9a53-341zdd68334b/home/dev  --> /home/dev/

**Solution:** Thanks for the help, this is what I ended up doing:

```
#Check if we are accessing my home folder from secondary drive
#If so change the color and trim the filepath to secondary /home
bash_prompt_command() {
    root_path=`pwd | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-(NF-2))}'`
    if [ $root_path = media ]; then #Shared drive
        #Trim path up to the home directory
        trim_path=${PWD#/media/devj/9a84a09e-80e9-44bd-9a53-342e3d48334c/}
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]$trim_path\[\033[38;5;214m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[38;5;214m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    fi
}

# init it by setting PROMPT_COMMAND
PROMPT_COMMAND=bash_prompt_command
```

Comment: [`PROMPT_DIRTRIM`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PROMPT_005fDIRTRIM) might be useful here.

Comment: What do you expect the prompt to look like when you're in some subdirectory X of drive A? And what do you expect it to look like when you're in some subdirectory Y of drive B?

Comment: Thanks for the tip of PROMPT_DIRTRIM, exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to check how deep the current working directory is from root so I can dynamically change the value of PROMPT_DIRTRIM. Basically I want drive a and drive b to look the same starting at the home directory within each drive. I want it to look like this if I am in my documents folder on drive B.
   /dev/home/Documents

Comment: To see how deep you are, you could count slashes in the path to the current directory in your `bash_prompt_command`: `slashes=${PWD//[!\/]}; depth=${#slashes}` and then set `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` to something based on that.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  I thought about doing that but ended up using this method instead.  
`trim_path=$(pwd)  trim_path=${trim_path#/media/devj/9a84a09e-80e9-44bd-9a53-342e3d48334c/}`

Comment: You could shorten that to `trim_path=${PWD#/media/devj/9a84a09e-80e9-44bd-9a53-342e3d48334c/}`

Answer (score 0):

`trim_path=${PWD#/*/*/*/}`

Substitute however many directories you want to omit from the beginning of path.